# Why is my jQuery script not triggering in Wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, autocomplete

I have tested the below script on a demo page which is not using any CMS.
The script is located in the index.php file and works just fine.

```
<form method="get" action="">
  <input id="label_search" type="text" value="" maxlength="40" name="inputText"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var options = {
      script:"includes/autosuggest.php?json=true&",
      varname:"input",
      minchars: 2,
      delay: 200,
      json:true,
      shownoresults:false,
      maxresults:15,
      timeout: 5000
  };

  var as_json = new bsn.AutoSuggest('inputText', options);
</script>
```

Now I want to use the same code in a Wordpress template file.
But nothing is happening. Seems like the script is not triggering at all.

I'm using user friendly URL's and have set custom permalinks to /%category%/%postname%.
Maybe that has something to say?

I know the bsn.AutoSuggest_2.1.3.js is running, because an "alert('hello')" test on the file is executed on page load.

What could be wrong?

This is my WP code:

sl_startpage.php:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: SL - Start page
*/ 
  get_header(); ?>
  <div id="myArea">
  <?php
    include_once('includes/storeLocator/sl_header.php');
  ?>
  </div>

<?php 
  get_footer(); 
?>
```

This is the (simplyfied) code in sl_header.php:

```
  <div id="sl-header">
    <form method="get" action="">
      <input id="label_search" type="text" value="" maxlength="40" name="product_search"/>
    </form>                   
  </div>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    var options = {
        script:"includes/autosuggest.php?json=true&",
        varname:"input",
        minchars: 2,
        delay: 200,
        json:true,
        shownoresults:false,
        maxresults:15,
        timeout: 5000
    };
    var as_json = new bsn.AutoSuggest('product_search', options);
  </script>
```

Any suggestions anyone?

This is the plugin I use:
http://www.brandspankingnew.net/archive/2007/02/ajax_auto_suggest_v2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright!
After about 20 hours of research, I found the answer in a [blog by Ryan Pharis](http://ryanpharis.com/2008/10/ajax-for-wordpress-plugins-using-jquery/).
As I was suspecting, it was an easy solution.

Wordpress is using "user friendly URLS".
Therefore my path ended up like this: 
http://www.mysite.com/includes/autosuggest.php?json=true&

The REAL path is this: 
http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/themes/my_theme/includes/autosuggest.php?json=true&

My script cannot be located in an external .js script, because I need to get the URL from Wordpress. So I did this:

```
<?php $site_url = bloginfo('template_url'); ?>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    var options = {
        script:"<?php echo $site_url; ?>includes/autosuggest.php?json=true&",
```

Now my script works and I'm a happy camper.

Answer (score 1):

```
includes/autosuggest.php?json=true&
```

This is the url, right? I think it will end up being relative to the file that your template generates so if the url of the autosuggest.php is at:

```
http://yourserver.com/includes/autosuggest.php
```

..and you use the template to generate the html for the following two (made-up) urls:

```
http://yourserver.com/frontpage/
http://yourserver.com/categories/anotherpage/
```

I'm pretty sure the it will be looking here for your include:

```
http://yourserver.com/frontpage/includes/autosuggest.php
http://yourserver.com/categories/anotherpage/includes/autosuggest.php
```

..when you probably want it to look at:

```
http://yourserver.com/includes/autosuggest.php
```

..so try adding a '/' to the front of your url in that JSON and see if that rectifies it.

Comment: Wow, that was quick.

I discovered it was my own mistake.
I was using "another/dir/sl_header.php"

Once I set the correct path, things are triggering.

Now I only have the problem that is does not locate the  autosuggest.php file.

As you can see from bsn.AutoSuggest('product_search', options), I am using the correct name of the text box.

Firebug just gives me a 404 Not Found.

Comment: I've had another go, it could be due to it resolving to a relative url from your generated page (see edit above)

Comment: My URL is this: http://localhost/mywebsite/store-locator. The "physical" path to the file is: http://localhost/mywebsite/includes/autosuggest.php. Since I'm using user friendly URLs in Wordpress CMS, I don't think any of your above suggestions would work. One reason is that if I create test.php which displays 'Hello world', and place this in the root directory, I will not be able to access it through http://localhost/mywebsite/test.php. Wordpress will only show a default template with the text "Nothing found".